# Alternatives to infowindow

Tags: google-maps

On of the drawbacks of google maps infowindows is that map will move to make room for the infowindow to display. ebubble( http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ebubble.html) overcomes this limitation, it doesn't move the map. However. it has its own limitations (you can't leave it on, like the infowindow, due to the way it works (it immediately hides). Also, the bubble, being absolutely positioned, might get cropped)

Are there more alternatives to the infowindow that doesn't move the map, besides ebubble?

Comment: bpmarker (http://www.gmaptools.com/bpmarker.php) is promising. It's not an infowindow exactly, it behaves like a label like is never cropped

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs (which aren't totally clear from your description), you might consider [MapTooltip](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/03/announcing-maptooltip/), which lets you put arbitrary HTML into a tooltip. I haven't used it, but it's mentioned in [this excellent presentation on Google Maps](http://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dggjrx3s_153hdf2s6cm).

Alternatively, you might be able to make the InfoWindow do what you want with some event handling code. [movestart](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.movestart) and [the InfoWindow's onOpenFn](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions.onOpenFn) might let you do this - try catching movestart and remembering the map's position, then in your onOpenFn restore the position. This might look ugly, though.

Comment: Thanks aem. MapTooltip has one drawback. If the maker is close to the edge of the map, the tooltip gets cropped.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the [EWindow](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/ewindows.htm)?

Comment: EWindow also crops if the marker is close to the edge of the map

Comment: Didn't you say you wanted a window that doesn't move the map?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the Google Maps Flash API, there is a way of opening info windows without the map panning. The info window stays open until the user closes it. The user can move the map while the window remains open.

Link to example [here](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/SmartInfoWindowDemo/SmartInfoWindowDemo.html). 
Right click map to view source.

Comment: Dan, the infowindow here works as I think it should. I guess I haven't mentioned before that there is an undocumented option for the infowindow, {suppressMapPan:true} that prevents the map from moving. However, if marker is at the edge, it also gets cut off.

Here is a discussion about it 
http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/9f61db38b0ccbec4/1f4ddc45c117500f?lnk=gst&q=clustering

Comment: Ups, I didn't finish my thought. Well, I rather not got the flash route. Thanks though, for pointing out the possibility

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using InfoBubble? I like this implementation better than the default InfoWindow.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html