# Google maps infowindow alternative

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I tried infobox which seems to be the most malleable alternative of the standard infowindow which can't be styled as I want. It seems that infobox has some problems to, which I posted here and I didn't get any answers.

So my new question is: Is there any other option? I mean a good one. I found on this website two other examples which were very ugly to work with. I prefer standard infowindow better than them.

Comment: What are some of the others you considered 'ugly'? Have you seen infobubble? http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/

Comment: do you think that if i found this usefull i will lose my time wrinting here? it seems that google maps v3 its not better than v2

Answer (score 0):

Check these out:

- [Alternatives to infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121252/alternatives-to-infowindow)
- [Googlemap custom infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364533/googlemap-custom-infowindow)
- [Styling Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634991/styling-google-maps-infowindow)

First one has plenty of links regarding custom InfoWindows, and the second and third might help you stylizing either a default or custom InfoWindow.