# infoWindow that fills up map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to create a custom Google Maps infoWindow That will just open and fill over the map completely, instead of paning the map and setting the bubble over the marker?  Basically, what I'd like to do is have my markers on the map, then when a user clicks on a marker, it just opens the content in a panel that fits the entire map itself.  I looked at the options mentioned here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121252/alternatives-to-infowindow) but none of these seem to do what I'd like, they still open a "bubble" type of window. Has anyone done this or can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your custom info window is not so difficult, but it's a little bit complicated.
If you want to find the easiest way, I recommend InfoBubble library.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

If you want to just prevent map panning when the infoWindow open, you can specify an option:

```
var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   disableAutoPan : true
});
```

Comment: yeah, that was my next attempt, tackling a custom infowindow.  I just can't believe no one has done something like this before.  I'll be sure to keep everyone posted if i'm able to successfully complete it.